# I'm trying to do an easy if/else statements but for some reason I'm getting a runtime error

Tags: java, runtime-error

I used this code for an easy if/ else statement that will sum the answer if x was greater than y, and will subtract it if x was not greater than y ! For some reason I'm getting a run time error.

Can anyone help me with this?
The code is :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class calculation
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {      
        int x,y,answer;

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(" Enter x & Y " );

        x = kb.nextInt();
        y = kb.nextInt();

        if (x > y) {    
            answer = (x + y);
        }  
        else if (x < y) {
            answer=(x-y);
        }

    }
}
```

This is the message I get : Warning: The local variable answer is never read

Comment: Please edit your question to post the "runtime error" message and stacktrace.

Comment: "_...and will subtract it if it was anything else_."  If you want this to be true, you should use an "_else_" rather than an "_else if_".  You current code will do nothing if x and y are equal.

Comment: Andrew is steering you in the right direction.  Please read his answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the error you’re getting is something like this:

```
Foo.java:23: error: variable answer might not have been initialized
        System.out.print("answer is " + Integer.toString(answer));
```

then the problem is that `answer` might not have had any value set, and the computer gives up and prints an error message instead of possibly returning garbage.

How can `answer` not have a value set? You set `answer` to `x+y` if `x>y`, and if `x<y` you set `answer=x-y`; but what if `x=y`? There’s nothing that tells the computer what to do in that case. Even though `x` might not be equal to `y` for the particular inputs you typed into your program, Java gives you an error message now in the hopes that you would rather get an error now, when it can easily be fixed, than sometime much later when someone first inputs equal values of `x` and `y`.

You can fix this by changing `x>y` to `x>=y`, or `x<y` to `x<=y`, or by adding a third `x==y` case.

---

If the warning you are getting is

```
Warning: The local variable answer is never read
```

Then you need to add a statement that uses `answer` in some way, for example by adding this at the end of the method:

```
System.out.print("answer is " + Integer.toString(answer));
```

However, note that this is just a *warning*, not an *error*, so even though the message pops up, it should run just fine—try it! Of course, you won’t be able to see what value `answer` gets, because, as the warning says, `answer` is never read in the current code.

Comment: ... or by just using an **else** block.  Note that the question states that `answer` should be set to `x - y` if x is **NOT** greater than y.

Comment: I tried using else rather than else if but I don't think that it is suppose to work because I have another if statement

I want the answer to be x-y for x<y and x+y for x>y. I don't want to give any value to x=y

Comment: @Ryan - If you have another condition, you should include it in your question.  We can't help you if you don't show us your actual code.  Also, the compiler requires you to assign a value to a variable... That's, like, how it works.

Comment: @ Jahroy, I tried to do x<=y and I got the same problem. There is something wrong with answer and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I tried using :        if (x>y) 
    answer= (x+y);
    
  else
    answer=(x-y);
 and got the same result

Comment: Thank you very much Andrew Neitsch

Answer (score 0):

```
int x,y, answer;

Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println(" Enter x & Y " );

  x= kb.nextInt();
  y= kb.nextInt();

  if (x>y)
    answer= (x+y);
  else
    answer=(x-y);
System.out.println("the answer is " + answer);
```

and because you use the Scanner so you should import java.util.Scanner;

Comment: I imported the Scanner but I didn't write it here.
I am trying to have another condition. If x<y then the answer x-y
Thanks though